# List of books with images

Tags: tables, graphics, table-of-contents, book-design

I would like to buy some books from E-library so i'm thoughts why not i send them my request by make list of books in latex document to looks like that:

[image]

My thoughts :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ | c | m{5cm} | m{5cm} | }
    \hline
    Title of books  \\ \hline
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=60mm]{book1.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    &     &      \\ \hline
          &     &      \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{list of books}\label{L}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the precise question? Do you want a command that does this automatically? Do you need a `\listofbooks` command that lists your book then? Do you really need a floating environment for this?

Comment: yes of cours if possible i need \listofbooks command that lists my book with those information to looks like the image below

Comment: Do you need such a table for *each* book?  . Note your code produces `3` columns, which is not the case of the image.

Comment: yes i need for each book yes i just add it as try

Comment: Do you really send the dimensions when you order a book?

Comment: I really don't know but I think it's necessary information isn't it ?

Comment: It's necessary on the catalogue of a publisher or an antique bookseller, for I don't see why it should be necessary to order a book.

Comment: just add it please

Comment: @Bernard I'd certainly specify the price if I was ordering, though!

Comment: @cfr: In € or in £? Or in guineas ;o)

Comment: @Bernard Best not use sterling - there's only so much room in a box.

Comment: @cfr: I'd love in dongs!

Comment: @Bernard :-). I wonder what this stuff is really for. (Seems very unlikely it is for the stated purpose.)

Comment: @Bernard Do ebooks even have dimensions?

Comment: @cfr: To order E. Lear's books…

Comment: @Bernard Can't he order his own?

Comment: @cfr: Dimensions of the screen (rubber dimensions?).

Comment: @Bernard Shows my ignorance of the medium. I always thought one of the advantages was that you could reuse the same screen for different books. I didn't realise each one came with its own screen you have to fit onto your device.

Comment: dimension in case for paper version not for ebooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps (The special table design is left to the O.P. -- it depends on personal tastes)

[image]

[image]

I've defined a simple key-value interface that takes the relevant entries as values and typesets. Since all is set in a `group` and preset to be empty, the default values are all empty.

I also added a `.lob` file to be generated, i.e. a `list of books` which is included with `\listofbooks` and faking `\tableofcontents` for a moment.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{xkeyval}


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\makeatletter
\define@key{lob}{editeur}{%
  \def\kv@lob@editeur{#1}%
}

\define@key{lob}{broche}{%
  \def\kv@lob@broche{#1}%
}


\define@key{lob}{isbndix}{%
  \def\kv@lob@isbndix{#1}%
}

\define@key{lob}{isbntreize}{%
  \def\kv@lob@isbntreize{#1}%
}

\define@key{lob}{collection}{%
  \def\kv@lob@collection{#1}%
}

\define@key{lob}{langue}{%
  \def\kv@lob@langue{#1}%
}
\define@key{lob}{dimensions}{%
  \def\kv@lob@dimensions{#1}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\listofbooks}{O{List of Books}}{%
  \begingroup
  \def\contentsname{#1}
  \let\latex@@starttoc\@starttoc
  \def\@starttoc##1{\latex@@starttoc{lob}}
  \tableofcontents%
  \endgroup
}



\newcounter{ebook}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ebookentry}{sO{}+mm}{%
  \noindent%
  \begingroup
  \bfseries%
  \medskip
  \setkeys{lob}{broche={},langue={}, dimensions={},collection={},isbntreize={}, isbndix={}, editeur={},#2}%
  \refstepcounter{ebook}%
  \addcontentsline{lob}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theebook}#3}%
  \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}m{5cm}|C{5cm}|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{3}{|C{\dimexpr12cm+6\tabcolsep}|}{#3} \tabularnewline
      \hline
      Number: & \theebook  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      Broché: & \kv@lob@broche  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      Éditeur: & \kv@lob@editeur & \multirow{6}*{#4} \tabularnewline 
      \cline{1-2} 
      Collection: & \kv@lob@collection  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      Langue:  &\kv@lob@langue  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      ISBN 10: & \kv@lob@isbndix  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      ISBN 13:  &\kv@lob@isbntreize  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2}
      Dimensions:  &\kv@lob@dimensions  &  \tabularnewline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \medskip
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofbooks

\clearpage

\ebookentry[editeur={J.R.R. Tolkien}, dimensions={Very thick!}]{Lord Of the Rings}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente1}}
\ebookentry[editeur={William Shakespeare}, langue={Anglais}]{Hamlet}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente1}}
\end{document}
```

**Easier version** with 'autodefinition' of keys:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{xkeyval}


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\autodefinekey}[1]{%
  \define@key{lob}{#1}{%
    \expandafter\def\csname kv@lob@#1\endcsname{##1}%
  }
}


\autodefinekey{editeur}
\autodefinekey{broche}
\autodefinekey{isbntreize}
\autodefinekey{isbndix}
\autodefinekey{langue}
\autodefinekey{author}
\autodefinekey{dimensions}
\autodefinekey{collection}


\NewDocumentCommand{\listofbooks}{O{List of Books}}{%
  \begingroup
  \def\contentsname{#1}
  \let\latex@@starttoc\@starttoc
  \def\@starttoc##1{\latex@@starttoc{lob}}
  \tableofcontents%
  \endgroup
}



\newcounter{ebook}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ebookentry}{sO{}+mm}{%
  \noindent%
  \begingroup
  \bfseries%
  \medskip
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \setkeys{lob}{author={},broche={},langue={}, dimensions={},collection={},isbntreize={}, isbndix={}, editeur={},#2}%
  \refstepcounter{ebook}%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
    \addcontentsline{lob}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theebook}#3}%
  }   
  \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}m{5cm}|C{5cm}|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} \tabularnewline
      \multicolumn{3}{|C{\dimexpr12cm+6\tabcolsep}|}{#3} \tabularnewline
      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} \tabularnewline
      \hline
      Number: & \theebook  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      Broché: & \kv@lob@broche  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      Author: & \kv@lob@author  & \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      Éditeur: & \kv@lob@editeur & \multirow{6}*{#4} \tabularnewline 
      \cline{1-2} 
      Collection: & \kv@lob@collection  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      Langue:  &\kv@lob@langue  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      ISBN 10: & \kv@lob@isbndix  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2} 
      ISBN 13:  &\kv@lob@isbntreize  &  \tabularnewline
      \cline{1-2}
      Dimensions:  &\kv@lob@dimensions  &  \tabularnewline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \medskip
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofbooks

\clearpage

\ebookentry[editeur={J.R.R. Tolkien}, dimensions={Very thick!}]{Lord Of the Rings}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente1}}
\ebookentry[author={William Shakespeare}, langue={Anglais}]{Hamlet}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente1}}
\ebookentry[author={Monty Python}, langue={Anglais}]{Collected Words}{}
\ebookentry[author={City of New York}, langue={Anglais}]{Phone dictionary of New York}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! (+1). The O.P. seems to have forgotten a book has an *author*… Just a small comment: `Editeur` should be `Éditeur`. And why not adding a `weight` field (useful for Tolkien!) :o)

Comment: yes i forgot it yes could you add those too

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks, I've added `Éditeur` in the code, but not in screenshot. French language is a miracle to me ;-) Apparently, `Éditeur` is not the same as author?

Comment: please could you add ' auteur=author'

Comment: @Educ: Done, but I used `author` instead. Just change the relevant entries in the 2nd code